# AviSaveOptions() dialog window is distorted!

Tags: c++, hebrew, vfw

I'm using windows XP , hebrew version.
I am trying to save an AVI file using the Video For Windows API in C++, when I run the AviSaveOptions() function, the dialog opens as a thin unclickable strip at the corner of the screen.
Would it have anything to do with the language (Hebrew)? maybe with the vfw driver itself? what might cause a windows dialog window to be distorted/invisible?

thanks
Roey

Answer (score 0):

Can't really answer your question, but I've seen problems with localized versions of AVISaveOptions dialog. The Swedish Windows XP version of it never showed but one codec, although more were installed on the system. Verified on several Swedish XP installations. Other languages we could test didn't show this. Submitted a bug report to MS, and to my great surprise, never heard back.

The AVIFile API in general seems to be spec'ed and and implemented by a bunch of drunken monkeys, so I wouldn't be hugely surprised if they had botched the Hebrew version beyond recognition.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar distortion of the AVISaveOptions dialog, only with Windows 7 Ultimate (English) with the Arabic language pack installed and the display language set to Arabic.

For me the workaround was setting the uiFlags parameter to ICMF_CHOOSE_PREVIEW, check the [AVISaveOptions documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#footerLink). Not an ideal solution if you don't want the preview functionality on the dialog, but at least it is visible and displayed correctly.